# Sharepoint 2010 : error details for built-in activities

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I try to make a short simple workflow in Visual Studio 2010 with a CopyItemActivity.
When I run the workflow, I get a "Error occured" status.
I think I put a bad parameter... but without any detail, it is quite difficult to debug.
Is there a way to get more details ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of custom errors in the web.config of the web application. Further, you can enable call stack to get even more information.

Set `CallStack` to true in */Configuration/SharePoint/SafeMode*:

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" ... />
```

Set `mode` to Off in */Configuration/system.web/customErrors*:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Comment: It was.
I think these configs are for the ASP.NET errors.
My errors are Workflow errors.

Comment: It seems I've got little more that I was thinking in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

All workflow errors are logged (if configured) in ULS logs, stored in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs`. You can look for `Unexpected` log entry. No additional changes in web.config should be necessary. Those information are unavailable from the website by design. Alternatively, you can use PowerShell for querying logs on the server. Something like this (didn't tested, but i hope it will work):

```
Get-SPLogEvent -StartTime "16/09/2012 6:00" -EndTime "16/09/2012 18:00" 
| Where-Object {$_.Level -eq "Unexpected"} 
| select timestamp, process, level, message, correlation  
| Format-Table –Wrap
```